# Why can't values set in a cat | while loop be read after the loop?

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to shell scripting and I have written a script to flag values within a `while` loop but if I try to access those values after the loop, it is returning null values.  Why?

```
#!/bin/sh
cat PLAYARTE_TXT.txt|while read line
do
    count1=$(echo $line|wc -c)
    a=37
    if [[ $count1 -eq  $a ]];
    then
        b=0 
    else
        c=1
        break
    fi
done
if [ "$b" -eq "0" -a "$c" -ne "1" ];
then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is redundant and is the cause to your problem because the "|" pipe creates a subshell. That's why when you go out of the while loop, the value of `$b` is "lost". just redirect the file to while read loop

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
 count1=$(echo "$line"|wc -c)
 a=37
 if [ "$count1" -eq  "$a" ];then
   b=0
 else
   c=1
   break
 fi
done  < "PLAYARTE_TXT.txt"
if [[ "$b" = 0 && "$c" != 1 ]];then
 echo success
else
 echo failure
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how do i specify the file where it has to read

Comment: what do you mean? the file is redirected. see my code again. Otherwise, if you are talking about passing the file name to the script, you can use `$1` (or `$@`)